# Cómo puedo hacer para guardar un dato que almacene un rango de horas en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Es una base de datos que gestiona el uso de un centro de computo, un docente puede recibir 2 horas de reserva del centro de computo, pero un tutor (instructor) puede obtener sólo una hora. No tienen que chocar las horas de reservas. ¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer para registrar la reserva de una persona pero que no sea mayor a lo que se le permite o que me recomiendan hacer?

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```
CREATE DATABASE `pruebaprogra3`;

USE pruebaprogra3;

CREATE TABLE `cargo` (
  `id_cargo` int(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `cargo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `horas` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `tipoUso` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `cargo` (`id_cargo`, `cargo`, `horas`, `tipoUso`) VALUES
(001, 'Docente', 2, 'Clases'),
(002, 'Tutor', 1, 'Practicas');



CREATE TABLE `dia` (
  `id_dia` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `dia` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `dia` (`id_dia`, `dia`) VALUES
(1, 'Lunes'),
(2, 'Martes');



CREATE TABLE `hora` (
  `id_hora` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `hora` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `hora` (`id_hora`, `hora`) VALUES
(1, 8),
(2, 9),
(3, 10);



CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `id_persona` int(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `segNombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `segApellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_Cargo` int(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `personas` (`id_persona`, `nombre`, `segNombre`, `apellido`, `segApellido`, `id_Cargo`) VALUES
(001, 'Edgardo', 'Armando', 'Espadero', 'Navas', 001),
(002, 'Cristian', 'Aarón', 'Ayala', 'Chacón', 002);


CREATE TABLE `Reserva` (
  `numDia` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_hora` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `id_persona` int(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `Reserva` (`numDia`, `id_hora`, `id_persona`) VALUES
(1, 1, 001),
(1, 2, 002);

ALTER TABLE `cargo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_cargo`);


ALTER TABLE `dia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_dia`);

ALTER TABLE `hora`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_hora`),
  ADD KEY `hora` (`hora`);

ALTER TABLE `personas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_persona`),
  ADD KEY `id_Cargo` (`id_Cargo`);


ALTER TABLE `Reserva`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`numDia`,`id_hora`),
  ADD KEY `id_persona` (`id_persona`),
  ADD KEY `id_hora` (`id_hora`);


ALTER TABLE `cargo`
  MODIFY `id_cargo` int(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `personas`
  MODIFY `id_persona` int(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `personas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `personas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Cargo`) REFERENCES `cargo` (`id_cargo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Reserva`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Reserva_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id_persona`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Reserva_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_hora`) REFERENCES `hora` (`id_hora`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Reserva_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`numDia`) REFERENCES `dia` (`id_dia`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: En MySQL puedes hacerlo mediante un `TRIGGER` que emula el `check constraint` del estándar SQL. En resumen el `TRIGGER` llamaría a una función que haría la comparación antes de insertar... la comparación se puede hacer también en el mismo `TRIGGER`.  [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/) explicado paso por paso. ¿Por qué una función es mejor?  Porque hay que pensar también en las actualizaciones... Debes definir otro `TRIGGER` que controle los `UPDATE` y la función te serviría para los dos casos. En el enlace se explica también lo del `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITO: Perdón, anteriormente no me di cuenta que no había incorporado una validación para verificar  que no haya reservas en ese horario. Con las modificaciones realizadas en el **procedimiento** y la **tabla** ya se realiza esta validación.

Mira, en **mi opinión** creo que lo correcto seria modificar tu tabla 'Reserva'. Supongamos que un **profesor** desea realizar una reserva de 2 horas. Siguiendo tu estructura deberías insertar 2 registros en tu tabla, sin embargo estamos hablando de una sola reserva. Por ello te propongo reemplazar tu tabla una con la siguiente estructura por la siguiente:

```
TABLE `reservas` (
  `id_reserva` int NOT NULL,
  `id_persona` int NOT NULL,
  `id_hora_inicio` int NOT NULL,
  `id_hora_fin` int NOT NULL,
  `id_dia` int NOT NULL
)
```

Luego de realizar este cambio podrías guardar las reservas en un solo registro mas allá de la cantidad de horas que abarque la misma, haciendo uso de un procedimiento almacenado. Por ejemplo:

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `reservasInsert`( in _id_persona int, in _id_hora_inicio int, in _id_hora_fin int, in _id_dia int)
BEGIN

DECLARE horas_reserva  int;
DECLARE hora_inicio  int;
DECLARE hora_fin  int;
DECLARE max_horas  int;
DECLARE coincidencias  int default 0;

SET hora_inicio =  (SELECT hora from hora WHERE id_hora = _id_hora_inicio);
SET hora_fin =  (SELECT hora from hora WHERE id_hora = _id_hora_fin);
SET horas_reserva = hora_fin - hora_inicio;
SET max_horas = (SELECT c.horas FROM personas p inner join cargo c on c.id_cargo = p.id_cargo where p.id_persona = _id_persona);

SET coincidencias = (select count(id_reserva) from reserva r 
inner join hora h on r.id_hora_inicio = h.id_hora 
inner join hora hf on r.id_hora_fin = hf.id_hora  
where hora_inicio >= h.hora and  hora_inicio < hf.hora and r.id_dia = _id_dia limit 1);

if (horas_reserva <= max_horas  ) then
    if(coincidencias = 0) then
        INSERT INTO `Reserva` (`id_persona`, `id_hora_inicio`, `id_hora_fin`, `id_dia` ) VALUES
        (_id_persona, _id_hora_inicio, _id_hora_fin, _id_dia);
        SELECT @@identity AS id;
    else
        select -1; 
    end if;
else
    SELECT 0;

end if;

END
```

Como puedes ver, lo que hace este procedimiento es verificar que la persona que esta tratando de realizar la reserva no se exceda con la cantidad de horas que tiene permitidas. En el caso de pasar la validación, se procede a realizar el INSERT y luego se retorna el ID del registro ingresado. Caso contrario retorna 0 (Cero).

Espero que te sirva. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Como soluciona esto el problema de los cruces en los horarios?

Comment: Gracias por hacerme caer en cuenta. Ya esta editado.